# Manage application stack with systemd

Tags: systemd

I have a stack of three applications I'd like to manage with `systemd`. I'll refer to them as `app1`, `app2` and `app3`.

`app1` and `app2` are independent, and are composed of two processes each.

`app3` is dependent on both `app1` and `app2`, and is also composed of two processes.

I'd like to create something like the following:

- have some way to launch either of the independent apps (`app1` and `app2`).
- have the option to launch services within all three apps individually (ex: start only `process1` of `app1`)
- have some overreaching way of starting this whole stack - launch both processes `app1` and `app2` and, once those are up, launch both processes of `app3`.

In a 'normal' state, the whole stack should go up every morning and stop as the apps close of their own accord - then run again the following morning.

I've thought of two ways to do this:

1. Split each process as a service (`app1-process1.service`, etc), and group respective apps as targets (`app2.target` composed of `app2-process1.service` and `app2-process2.service`).
2. Create a template service for each app `app1-@.service` which accepts arguments as to which service to launch. I'll then have to set some default that will launch both processes (ex: `app1-@all.service`)

What do you think? what would be the best approach to do this? I'd really appreciate any advice.

Thanks!